# Suggest sample hive queries with example for table creation, update and delete using hive 0.14

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

please any one help me to create hive transactional table using hive 0.14. Also, suggest with example how to perform update and delete operation in the records from the created hive table

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We do not write code here, we help you fix **your** code. Show us what have you tried? What worked? What didn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
Need to add additional settings in hive-site.xml and
```

create table with ACID output format support.

```
New Configuration Parameters for Transactions
 hive.support.concurrency – true
 hive.enforce.bucketing – true
 hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode – nonstrict
 hive.txn.manager –org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
 hive.compactor.initiator.on – true
 hive.compactor.worker.threads – 1


You can also set the parameters by running above lines on hive terminal for temp.,
then run below queries to perform create, insert, update, delete, select operations on table.

**1.Create HiveTest table with ACID support**

create table HiveTest 
   (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,
     Salary Int,Department String) 
   clustered by (department) into 3 buckets 
   stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

**2. INSERT**

insert into table HiveTest 
     values(1,'Rohit','MD',88000,'Development');

insert into table HiveTest 
     values(2,'anil','CEO',99999,'IT');

**3. SELECT**

SELECT * FROM hivetest;

**4.UPDATE**

 update HiveTest 
    set salary = 111111 
    where employeeid = 2;

**5. DELETE**

 delete from HiveTest
     where employeeid=1;

**6. SELECT**`enter code here`

SELECT * FROM hivetest;

'Insert into ..' statement cannot be used for complex datatypes.
 Hive does not support literals for complex types, so it is not possible to use them in INSERT...VALUES clauses.

Thanks
```